# when i am installing react in vscode project its giving me this error

Tags: error-handling, react-error-boundary

PS C:\Users\X1\ReactProjects> npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\X1\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\X1\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\X1\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-17T10_33_39_767Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\X1\ReactProjects> node -v
v20.6.1

when i am installing react its giving me this error